# Property 'pipe' does not exist on type 'Promise'

Tags: angular

I am trying to implement error handling in my code and getting the following error. I am not sure what the problem is ?

error TS2339: Property 'pipe' does not exist on type 'Promise'.
src/app/fund/fund.component.ts(166,34): error TS2345: Argument of type '(err: any) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type '(err: any, caught: Observable<{}>) => ObservableInput'.
  Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'ObservableInput'

Code
import { map, catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';

```
saveFund() {
        if (this.SelectedFundId === 0) {
            this.fundService.createFund(this.FundDetails).then((result) => {
                if (result) {
                    this.getFundDetails(this.SelectedFundId);
                    this.EditMode = !this.EditMode;
                }
            });
        } else {
            this.fundService.updateFund(this.FundDetails).then((result) => {
                if (result) {
                    this.getFundDetails(this.SelectedFundId);
                    this.notify.success('Fund Details Successfully Updated');
                    this.EditMode = !this.EditMode;
                }
            }) .pipe(catchError (err => {
                this.notify.error('An Error Has Occured While Updating Fund Details');
            }));
        }
    }
```

Comment: `pipe` is a method of `Observable`, it's supposed to be used with `Observables`, not `Promises`

Comment: How to handle error on promise

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use 'pipe' operator because it's **rxjs operator**. In your case you can use **catch(error)** like this:

```
saveFund() {
    if (this.SelectedFundId === 0) {
        this.fundService.createFund(this.FundDetails).then((result) => {
            if (result) {
                this.getFundDetails(this.SelectedFundId);
                this.EditMode = !this.EditMode;
            }
        }).catch(err => {
           this.notify.error('An Error Has Occured While Creating Fund Details');
        });
    } else {
        this.fundService.updateFund(this.FundDetails).then((result) => {
            if (result) {
                this.getFundDetails(this.SelectedFundId);
                this.notify.success('Fund Details Successfully Updated');
                this.EditMode = !this.EditMode;
            }
        }).catch(err => {
            this.notify.error('An Error Has Occured While Updating Fund Details');
        });
    }
}
```

Hope this will wotk for you!

Comment: If you notice i have and if else statement. the catch should be catching errors for both. Hence I think shouldnt be there a common catch for both the if and else. At the moment your proposed answer only catches error for the else block

Comment: I know this could be probably redundant, but why not putting another .catch in first if, in first call to promise?

Comment: I understand what you are trying to do, but you just cannot use .pipe on Promise.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `pipe` which as method of `Observable` you will need to use either `.then()` or `.catch()` the latter being the method to handle errors in Promises

Answer (score 1):

**pipe** is a method of **Observable**, it's supposed to be used with the `Observables`, not Promises. To handle an error from **Promise** use **catch** method like so:

```
this.fundService.updateFund(this.FundDetails)
  .then((result) => {
    if (result) {
      this.getFundDetails(this.SelectedFundId);
      this.notify.success('Fund Details Successfully Updated');
                this.EditMode = !this.EditMode;
    }
  })
  .catch(err => console.log(err));
```